# Hide default marker tooltip in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, tooltip, marker

I am creating a custom marker tooltip:

```
marker.bindTooltip("title");
marker.addTo(map);
```

However, after opening the custom one, after a while the "default" tooltip appears additionally.

[image: marker tooltip]

How to hide the default tooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`title` option of your `L.Marker`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker-title) to an empty string.